# Which file system for an SD card permanently mounted on my Mac?

Tags: disk-utility, filesystem, mount, disk-format, sd-card

To extend my limited Macbook Pro storage I keep a 128 GB micro SD always mounted in the SD card reader (thanks to Nifty Minidrive). I use it for *static* files:  music, photo and video files I need to refer to, but that don't change often.

The SD card is formatted in `exFAT` and from time to time it gets disconnected when I bump my Mac during my commute, and to fix the file system corruption I need to mount it on a Windows PC (since `Disk Utility` doesn't seem to be able to fix it).

Since I'll use this SD card only on my Mac, should I format it as `HFS+` instead?
I've read that a *journaled file system* can cope better with this kind of problems, and `Disk Utility` could repair it if needed.

Is there any risk (i.e. excessive wear on the SD card) in formatting my micro SD in `HFS+`?

Will be `HFS+` more reliable than `exFAT`?

Comment: No SD card could be called 'reliable'. Don't keep your only copy of anything on one.

Comment: @Tetsujin That's for sure. I still keep a backup of that data on my Time Capsule and on an external USB disk. My question is about **which file system is more reliable for this use**. You know, it's annoying when you are at work, need to read **that** file you left on the SD, but the SD isn't mounted because the file system got corrupted, and the other copy you have is at home!

Comment: I'd take a guess that GUID/HFS+ would be more 'fixable on the fly' but I have no hard evidence, so can't provide an actual answer.

Comment: Since I first wrote my question, I reformatted my SD card in `GUID` + `HFS+`, and didn't experience any file system issue even after several "accidents" (mostly card bumped and power loss). I got it disconnected a few times, got warnings that reminded me to clean unmont the card before disconnecting, but didn't experience any real issue. So in for this application, `HFS+` seems to be more "robust" than `exFAT`. Still can't tell if `HFS+` can affect SD card life in a different way than `exFAT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried for myself, formatted the SD card in `GUID` + `HFS+`, and after several months it seems more reliable than `exFAT` for this use case.

When the  card is accidentally disconnected the OS shows a notification, but as I unplug and replug the card, the system checks it for defects, and run `fsck` in the background if needed (it happens rarely, and it takes less than a minute).

So this setup it's a good solution from my point of view.

It's worth remembering that you should use it **only for static files**, i.e. data that you read often, but write seldom.